# Event button in view added not work, iOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I developed app for iOS and i trie catch the event in a button, that button is in a xib and i create a method when touch up inside.

and i present de view the following form

```
DetailNoticiaController *detail = [[DetailNoticiaController alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:detail.view];
```

detail.view contain the button, when the button is pressed, the app crashed and not show the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `detail` deallocates as you don't save it somewhere. You may try code below:

```
DetailNoticiaController *detail = [[DetailNoticiaController alloc] init];
[self addChildViewController:detail];
[self.view addSubview:detail.view];
```

Helpful link - ["Creating Custom Container View Controllers"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW6)